# Feature stuck on Overridden - "Overrides" column empty, "Default" not

Tags: 7, features

I have a feature which is constantly stuck at overriden, no matter how times I try to revert or re-create it. I have gone through the standard checklist, including uninstalling and reinstalling, and checking the correct includes are present in .info file and .module file.

On the "Review Overrides" panel, however, I have the attached screenshot. Noticed that the default contains an array full of field settings, but the overrides just contains FALSE:

[image: Discrepancy between Default and Overrides column]

It would seem that my database doesn't contain this info when it should, and refuses to take it from the Feature?

UPDATE:

I checked the .info file and they seemed all in place; however I suspect that the second cause indicated by the accepted answer below could be the problem. There are currently two modules that remain in a persistent "Overidden" state, and they both share: "CTOOLS EXPORT API -> context:context:3" and "FEATURES_API -> api:1". On initial investigation it would seem that these two items are inherent in the feature, although perhaps I could remove the CTOOLS EXPORT API item by removing the ctools dependency? Argh...

Comment: It could as well be a module is not enabled but your feature contains an export from that module's setting and you're trying to import it into the database. It happened to me before and you just need to fix your feature's dependencies and add the missing ones or just `drush pml` both the site you exported the feature from and the site you're trying to import into and check the differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two possible reasons for this that I can think of: one is that the .info file for your feature is out of step with the other files. This can happen when you are creating or updating a feature and you don't wait for the little animated timer gif to stop before clicking on another option. It occasionally happens for other reasons, such if you do a git merge automatically with changes from another developer.

To fix this, you generally need to go through your .info file one item at a time and check it corresponds to the other files, so there are no items in any of those files that are not in the .info.

The other reason is if two features overlap in some way. If you have the same configuration item in two features, one of them will usually fail to revert. You may need to refactor your features to prevent this.

Comment: Thankyou. I checked the .info file and they seemed all in place; however I suspect that the second cause you indicated could be the problem. There are currently two modules that remain in a persistent "Overidden" state, and they both share: "CTOOLS EXPORT API -> context:context:3" and "FEATURES_API -> api:1". On initial investigation it would seem that these two items are inherent in the feature, although perhaps I could remove the CTOOLS EXPORT API item by removing the ctools dependency? Argh...

Comment: Those API settings should not cause a problem. Another possibility: one of my colleagues had a lot of difficulty yesterday with a features module which he tracked down eventually to a naming clash. If that's a possibility, try renaming your feature module by giving it a unique prefix so none of its functions can be misidentified as hook implementations belonging to other modules/themes.

Answer (score 1):

Another cause I encountered: After updating to features 2, for some reason (possibly a git merge) I still had the xxxx.features.field.inc files in addition to field_base and field_instance. Removing the field.inc files solved the problem.